# Moving SQL Server database folders to different drive with same letter to extend C partition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need some advice on moving my SQL Server files so that I can extend my `C:` partition as it’s running out of free space current size is 40GB.

In order to do so I need unallocated space to the right of that drive which I have space but it is my SQL database files

```
D:\Program Files\   
    MSAS10_50.MSSQLSERVER   
    MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER  
    MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER
```

and their sub folders.

My idea is to shrink D: by 700GB to create 100GB of space that I can give to C:, Take the left over 700GB and make an F:, verify F: has the same permissions as D:, stop all SQL services and copy all the data from D: to F:.

After the copy completes I plan on changing the drive letters of D: to H: and F: to D: and Restarting the server. Does anyone know if this can be done?
The server is Windows server is 2008 R2 Std with SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: I'm not sur to understand why you want to move your file from D to F to D but I think there is no problem to do this. It's quite easy also to move a file to another disk and to make SQL Server works with the new file with the SQL instruction 'sp_detach' and 'sp_attach'

Comment: Polux2, I have no unallocated space to the right of C only D so if I shrink D then I need to move data around to have the unallocated space next to C to Extend C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options here: [How to resize the primary partition in Windows Server 2008?](https://serverfault.com/questions/108633/how-to-resize-the-primary-partition-in-windows-server-2008)

You cannot expand it if there are other partition in between your partition and free disk space (ie. on its right). 
You can only expend when it is followed by empty space on its right. 
When you shrink the second partition, it shrinks to its right. It won't help you because it won't release space to the left of the 2nd partition.

If you have the possibility to temporary remove D, the easiest may be to:

- Mode content of D to a temporary disk
- Remove D partition => free space to the right of C
- Expend C
- Add a new D drive
- Copy data from the temporary disk back on D

Another option once you have free space after D, could be to create a third partition after D and mount it as folder in C.